# Tensorflow lite Pipeline Changes because of Cast Reordering

Tags: android, tensorflow, protocol-buffers, tensorflow-lite

This issue is regarding Cast-reordering that comes as an unwanted attribute during TFLite conversion. We have a pb file wherein reshape operator occurs before Cast operation. We basically wanted a reshape operation which will be faster in mobile GPU, to be executed first, followed by Cast operator which will run in CPU. But due to unknown reasons, the flow of execution jumps from GPU to CPU in the middle itself, by executing the Cast operator first. These reshape and Cast conversions were done in this order, in order to gain some speed. Copying data from mobile GPU to mobile CPU if it is done in lesser dimensions, rather than 4 dimensions, proves to be a good factor in deciding the model running time.Even though in the pb level, Cast is shown after the Reshape operator, on tf-lite level, the positions are getting changed. When the graph is analysed on benchmark tool and Netron, an additional input called Cast-reorder is introduced. What is this Cast reordering and how can that be eliminated?

1) When cutting off the graph at Reshape level, the graph is as expected, but without Cast operator.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit unclear from the description what is happening.  I need some clarification:

1. Is the problem you are describing a bug in Toco?
2. Or is the problem a bug in GPU execution?

In either case, a visualization would help.

Also note that:

3. RESHAPE in GPU is pretty slow.  For any sort of reshape operations, you want to do that in CPU.
4. I'm not familiar with CAST, but it's an op not supported by GPU.  Also, all input to GPU must be in floating point.
5. Lesser dimensions doesn't help.  It will be always converted to GPU-friendly layout of PHWC4 format.